# Image on protected url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image, cordova

I am trying to retrieve an image from a protected url (at this point the user is locked in). The image should be set as source for an image-tag in my application (Which by the way is a Phonegap-App, so the SameOriginPolicy is no issue here).

Here is what I have so far:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://' + ip + ":" + port + '/art',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
    },
    timeout: 3000,
    cache: true,
    processData: false,
    success: function (requestData, status, jqXHR) {
        $("#cover").attr("src", requestData);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Unfortunately this won't work. Any idea or different approach is welcome.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, that I have no influence on the server, so I can't send the image base64 encoded.

Comment: Think you just need to authenticate via ajax, (which should give a session) and then you can change the src and it shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: Ah, it's the simple things. That was the right answer indeed, thank you very much.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!